# In Akeneo 2.1, how can I get a list of active locales?

Tags: localization, console, akeneo

I am creating a console Command in Akeneo 2.1, but I'm trying to get a list of active locales. How can I get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LocaleRepository provide a `getActivatedLocales` method which exactly do that. You can find it [here](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/2.1/src/Pim/Component/Catalog/Repository/LocaleRepositoryInterface.php#L24)

The locale repository code is `pim_catalog.repository.locale` and you can get the service in your command by calling `$this->getContainer()->get('pim_enrich.repository.locale');` (if your command is container aware of course).

Here is an example of a container aware command: [Query help command](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/2.1/src/Pim/Bundle/CatalogBundle/Command/QueryHelpProductCommand.php#L16)

Comment: The class returned is `Pim\Bundle\EnrichBundle\Doctrine\ORM\Repository\LocaleRepository`, which does not have the `getActivatedLocales()`-method. However, I managed to fix it with `$repository->findBy(['activated' => 1])`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah it seems that you need to use `pim_catalog.repository.locale` instead of `pim_enrich.repository.locale`. I'll edit your answer and accept it.

Comment: It seems that in Akeneo 4.0, you can not pass - '@pim_catalog.repository.locale' as a dependency into a custom service. But you can get it out of the container as said in the answer. You can pass the container into a service like as - '@service_container'